Understanding ANR Log: Process in Running State but WCHAN is wait_on_page_bit_common
I'm experiencing an ANR (Application Not Responding) issue in my Android application. Upon inspecting the ANR log, I noticed that the process is in the Running state, but its WCHAN is set to wait_on_page_bit_common. I'm uncertain whether this indicates that the process is blocked or if there's another underlying issue.
Here is an excerpt from the ANR log:
     "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
     | group="main" sCount=1 ucsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x72782fe8 self=0xb40000781cc2dbe0
     | sysTid=2855 nice=0 cgrp=foreground sched=0/0 handle=0x796346b4f8
     | state=R schedstat=( 253582185 325209172 189 ) utm=11 stm=13 core=0 HZ=100
     | stack=0x7ffb9cb000-0x7ffb9cd000 stackSize=8188KB
     | held mutexes=
     native: #00 pc 000000000009d3b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (mprotect+8)
     native: #01 pc 00000000000b1168  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so              (__allocate_thread_mapping(unsigned long, unsigned long)+200)
     native: #02 pc 00000000000b1380  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (pthread_create+272)
     native: #03 pc 000000000066f94c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateNativeThread(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, unsigned long, bool)+508)
     native: #04 pc 000000000057f1d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so     (art::Thread_nativeCreate(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, long, unsigned char)+152)
     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native method)
     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:884)
     - locked <0x0eb11d7c> (a android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$1)
     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.startLoadFromDisk(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:142)
     at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.<init>(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:130)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:568)
     - locked <0x024d8605> (a java.lang.Class<android.app.ContextImpl>)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences(ContextImpl.java:549)

There is no memory pressure, but the CPU is high on I/O wait.
Could someone help`
me understand the following:

What does it mean when a process is in the Running state but has a WCHAN set to wait_on_page_bit_common?
Is this an indication that the process is blocked, and if so, what could be causing it?
What steps can I take to diagnose and resolve this issue?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have focused on what might be the call on mprotect to be blocked, but again I am not sure why ANR reports the process is in R state.
